# How to scrape a site by loading content via triggering load more button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the titles for all blog post articles via a Load More button as set by my desired range for i in range(1,3):

At present I'm only able to capture the titles for the first page even though i'm able to navigate to the next page using selenium.

**Update:**
In a previous question ([How To Scrape Content With Load More Pages Using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646055/how-to-scrape-content-with-load-more-pages-using-selenium-python)) by myself the pagination url was captured via:

**Network Tab > Reload Page > Click Show more button > Select wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?...... Right Click Copy > Copy Link Address.**

However, i do not know how to capture similar url for the site learnwoo.com/blog. I'm not sure if it uses a different technique.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

# Selenium Routine
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Removes SSL Issues With Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('log-level=3') 
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
#options.add_argument('--headless') # Comment to view browser actions


# Get website url
urls = "https://learnwoo.com/blog/"
r = requests.get(urls)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
driver.get(urls)

productlist = []

for i in range(1,3):
    
    # Get Page Information
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'td_module_1')
    print(f'LOOP: start [{len(items)}]')

    for single_item in items:
        title = single_item.find('h3').text.strip()
        print('Title:', title)

        product = {
        'Title': title,
        }
        productlist.append(product)

    print()
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='next-page-tdi_5']"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.close()

# Save Results
df = pd.DataFrame(productlist)
df.to_csv('Results.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Scrape Content With Load More Pages Using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646055/how-to-scrape-content-with-load-more-pages-using-selenium-python)

Comment: Hi Marcus, in the previous question by myself the pagination url was captured via Network Tab > Reload Page > Click Show more button > Select wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?...... Right Click Copy > Copy Link Address.  However, i do not know how to capture similar url for the site https://learnwoo.com/blog/. I'm not sure if it uses a different technique.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: You can use API response to extract the desired data.From API response,I'm getting total 74 items where each page contains 6 items.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
    'id': '',
    'post_id': '0',
    'slug': 'home',
    'canonical_url': 'https://jooble.org/blog/',
    'posts_per_page': '6',
    'page': '0',
    'offset': '20',
    'post_type': 'post',
    'repeater': 'default',
    'seo_start_page': '1',
    'preloaded': 'false',
    'preloaded_amount': '0',
    'lang': 'en',
    'order': 'DESC',
    'orderby': 'date',
    'action': 'alm_get_posts',
    'query_type': 'standard',
    }

headers= {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
api_url='https://jooble.org/blog/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

productlist= []
for params['page'] in range(0,13):
    req = requests.get(api_url,params=params,headers=headers)

    e = req.json()['html']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(e,'lxml')
    
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'front__news-content-wrapper')
    for single_item in items:
        title = single_item.find('div', class_ = 'front__news-title')
        title=title.text.strip() if title else None
    
        product = {
        'Title': title,
        }
        productlist.append(product)

df = pd.DataFrame(productlist)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                          Title
0                   How to become an anesthesiologist
1                    How to Become a Flight Attendant
2                         How To Become An Influencer
3                        How to Become an Electrician
4        3 Common Job Scams You Should Stay Away From
..                                                ...
69                Exploring Main Types of Remote Work
70         14 books HR specialist should read. Part 2
71         14 books HR specialist should read. Part 1
72  Don’t do that: 7 mistakes ruining your job int...
73  Virtual job interview. Jooble tips how to nail it

[74 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Doesn't that API serve different data? Entry titles appears to be different. I also looked at a requests-only solution, but the post data object is just too complex, so Selenium seemed to be the better option here.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in `selenium context`, you could call `.click()`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='next-page-tdi_5']"))).click()
```

Concerning your xhr request comment - Note: Here it is not a `GET` it is a `POST` request (https://learnwoo.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?td_theme_name=Newspaper&v=11) and you have to send some additional payload with `requests`

##### Example

This example is based on `selenium 4` and uses its imports, may check https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#python-1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

urls = "https://learnwoo.com/blog/"

driver.get(urls)

productlist = []

for i in range(1,3):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'td_module_1')
    print(f'LOOP: start [{len(items)}]')

    for single_item in items:    
        product = {
        'Title': single_item.find('h3').text.strip(),
        }
        productlist.append(product)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='next-page-tdi_5']"))).click()

pd.DataFrame(productlist)
```

##### Output

```
    Title
0   5 Futuristic eCommerce Trends
1   9 Best Shopify Apps to Print Shipping Labels
2   Cloud Hosting VS VPS Hosting: A Comparison
3   10 Best WooCommerce Facebook Integration Plugins
4   Complete Guide to BigCommerce Security
... ...
91  How To Calculate ROI of Your Moodle LMS?
92  How and Where to Find Help for WordPress Begin...
93  Expert Speaks: In Conversation with Amir Helze...
94  A Complete Analysis: NetSuite WooCommerce Inte...
95  Review of Currency Switcher & Converter for Sh...
96 rows × 1 columns
```

Comment: How can i code to use driver located at "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe" as i'm getting error ====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 105.0.5195
Get LATEST driver version for 105.0.5195
Driver [C:\Users\Mark\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\105.0.5195.52\chromedriver.exe] found in cache

Comment: This is not an error per se, should still work - Not sure about the selenium version you work with, but this should give you an idea how to use hardcoded path with `selenium 4`:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#3-hard-coded-location

Comment: Having saved results to file, i just noticed the first 48 entries for page 1 are saved in a loop. Hence page 2 onwards is never saved. I add print(df.head(50)) at the end of the script and could see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to HedgHog's response: maybe the better way here is to use a `while` loop, as we don't know how many entries there are. I used a counter to breakout of the loop after the 5th loading - if you want to get all those entries, you just remove the counter.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC   
import time as t
import pandas as pd


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

big_list = []
counter = 1
url = 'https://learnwoo.com/blog/'
browser.get(url) 

while True:
    try:
        load_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[aria-label="load_more"]')))
        load_button.click()
        counter = counter + 1
        print('clicked to load more')
        t.sleep(3)
        entries = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3[class="entry-title td-module-title"]')))
        print('we have', len(entries), 'articles')
        big_list = [(x.text, x.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')) for x in entries]
        if counter > 5:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print('all done')
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['Article', 'Url'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
    Article     Url
0   5 Futuristic eCommerce Trends   https://learnwoo.com/future-ecommerce-trends/
1   9 Best Shopify Apps to Print Shipping Labels    https://learnwoo.com/best-shopify-apps-print-s...
2   Cloud Hosting VS VPS Hosting: A Comparison  https://learnwoo.com/cloud-hosting-vps-hosting/
3   10 Best WooCommerce Facebook Integration Plugins    https://learnwoo.com/best-woocommerce-facebook...
4   Complete Guide to BigCommerce Security  https://learnwoo.com/bigcommerce-security-guide/
...     ...     ...
286     A Comparison Between Omnichannel and Multichan...   https://learnwoo.com/omnichannel-multichannel-...
287     8 Winning Techniques for Off-page SEO   https://learnwoo.com/winning-techniques-for-of...
288     WooCommerce – How to Understand User Roles and...   https://learnwoo.com/woocommerce-understand-us...
289     7 Best Free WooCommerce Catalog Mode Plugins (...   https://learnwoo.com/free-woocommerce-catalog-...
290     Different WooCommerce Product Types Explained ...   https://learnwoo.com/woocommerce-different-pro...

291 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: Based on the counter being 'if counter > 1:' I noticed that both page 1 & 2 blog post articles are being scraped correctly. However on page 2, 3 additional items are scraped being the POPULAR POSTS (WooCommerce – How to Understand User Roles and Capabilities (with video), 7 Best Free WooCommerce Catalog Mode Plugins (with Video) & Different WooCommerce Product Types Explained in Detail (with Video)). Hence 48 + 48 = 96. When running script it states 'we have 99 articles'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue, @MarkWP. If you break it at counter > 1 (meaning the second load) you shouldn't get to page/load 3 & 4. If you get less items in dataframe than stated by printout of `len(..)`, then maybe there are titles without a link in them .. there are ways to debug this.

Comment: When you change line 36 to 'if counter > 1:' only 2 pages should be scrapped. Each pages has 48 blog post articles. Therefore 2 pages will have 96 blog post articles in total. The issues is that on page 2, 3 additional entries in the website footer (dark gray area) under POPULAR POSTS column are being scraped and added to overall list ... making the total count 99 entries

Comment: @MarkWP, your issue being .. you don't want the elements in footer being added to your dataframe? Then just remove the footer (footer children). Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/